# Can Tenser's Floating Disk be ridden?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I know the rules for [TFD in 3.5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/floatingDisk.htm) mention it can carry anything within its weight limit and can be directed by the caster within its range limits, but are there any rules about actually *riding* Tenser's Disk? I realize the capabilities implications of travel by hovering disk would probably be DM's call, but in general what's the consensus on using the TFD for self-transport?

Comment: And in case people are wondering, I just expect to use this for relatively simple stuff like hovering over shallow water, improv sledding, and possibly tightrope crossing. I am aware there is only so much you can do with something that takes you up to 3ft off the ground.

Comment: I assume you mean ride your own TFD.  You should be able to ride someone else's just fine!

Comment: we used it a bit more liberal; in the desert, i used it to shield myself from the sun. RAW, the disk would hover 20 ft. behind me, but the dm allowed it because it is not gamebreaking. i would definetly rule that you can hover around on it, because a mighty lvl 16 wizard should hover anyway, right?

Comment: What if you place one end of a 25’ beam on the disk with the other end on wheels or skis. Would the disk move at your normal rate if you sit on the end of the beam further than 20’ away from the Disk? For bonus points, if you have a passenger cast their own Disk for another Wizard to ride, could you make a train of Disks? If the Beam was designed better, it could have a seat that can extend past the 20’ to cause the Disk to move operated by a lever.

Comment: The other scenario I was thinking about was an L18 Monk (Base Movement: 30’, Unarmored Movement: +30’), with a level of Sorcerer (Expeditious Retreat, Long Strider +10’ MOV), Feat: Mobile (+10’ MOV), Feat: Ritual Caster (Tenser’s Floating Disk). I just have to figure out what contributes to “your normal speed,” and how Dashing affects Disk. I could haul 2-3 people quite a distance faster than most normal speeds. I also have to research how the Disk deals with water with the ability to move across liquids at L9 Monk: Unarmored Movement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No, you can not ride a Tenser's Floating Disk.**

There is a definitive, and official answer from the [WoTC 3.5 FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20030221a) (Pg. 91);

> **Can you ride your own Tenser’s floating disk?**
>   No. While you could command your Tenser’s floating disk to move close enough for you to sit upon it, it has no ability to move under its own power. It can follow you only at a maximum rate equal to your normal speed.

I would not say that being able to ride the disk is game-breaking or overpowered. Another first level spell exists called [Mount](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mount.htm) that is comparable to Tenser's floating disk. Depending on your need, maybe better. It is also a first level wizard spell. There is nothign to stop you from loading up your mount with jewels or gear, like you would a Floating Disk. You can also compare it to the spell [Levitate](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/levitate.htm), which is a second level spell that allows you to float 20-ft. from the ground. There exists a 4th level spell called Greater Floating Disk (Spell Compendium, Pg. 96) which has a fly-speed of 20-ft. and specifically says in the spell description that it allows characters to sit on it and ride it.

Comment: Link goes to error page. Can you ride someone *else's* disk, though?

Answer (score 8):

You could certainly ride it, it just has no propulsion of its own.  So by itself, it wouldn't do much good, and certainly wouldn't be equivalent to a mount.  But there are still some uses.  For instance, my wizard in the Skulls and Shackles campaign (Pathfinder, but close enough) used a Floating Disk with a long pole cut from a sapling as a skiff to cross a swamp.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, it has no propulsion of its own, merely following the caster around. However if you have a familiar with the share spells ability, you can [cast spells with a range of self on your familiar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm). This includes [Tenser's Floating Disk](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/floatingDisk.htm).

Because of this, cast the spell on your familiar then you can ride the disk while your familiar walks, crawls or flies around. They have to stay fairly low, but if they're fine with low flying you can get a pretty significant speed boost, as well as retaining your movement action each round by investing in a hawk familiar (60ft fly speed) or similar.

Comment: The disk has a range of close, not self, and also you don't cast it on any target, you just cast it into the air, so you wouldn't be able to "share" the spell and have it follow someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can ride the floating disk all you need is a ring of spell storing and a familiar to attune to the ring. Cast the spell into the ring have the familiar cast the spell. You hop on the disk grab an edge with hands and feet and have your familiar start flying in the direction you want to go. If you really wanna make an entrance strap a rowboat with a small sail on the disk and cast a modified regenerating fog cloud (silent image) on the boat get a familiar that can turn invisible and then sail into town like a boss.